# If A is next to B, how to automatically assert that B is next to A

Tags: database-design, ms-access, constraint, foreign-key

I am working in Access 2010.

Let's say I have a database that tracks where packages sit in a warehouse.

```
Table: Packages
PackageID (PK)
PackageHeight
PackageWidth
PackageWeight
PackageOwner
(etc)
```

Now I want to show what packages each package is next to.

For example, A is next to B and M.

```
Table: PackageNextTo
ID (PK), PackageID (Packages.PackageID, FK), NextToPackageID(Packages.PackageID, FK)
1, A, B
2, A, M
```

So when I look up `A`, I find out it is next to `B` and `M`.

But when I look up `B`, I also want to find out it is next to `A`.... and when I look up M, I want to find out it is next to `A` and also, for example, next to `T`.  (but M and B are not necessarily next to each other).  Do I have to define these relationships explicity by adding records as follows:

```
Table: PackageNextTo
ID (PK, AutoIncrement), PackageID, NextToPackageID
1, A, B
2, A, M
3, B, A
4, M, A
5, M, T
6, T, M
```

OR is there a way to automatically say if `x` is next to `y` then `y` is next to `x`.

(OR a better way to structure this data altogether!!)

In human terms I see redundancy between records 1 and 3 above, and between 5 and 6 above, and so on.... but I don't know if this is redundant to a database or if the database needs this explicitly called out.

If the database requires this explicit, is there a way to run a macro or query that will automatically create (B,A) when (A,B) is defined?

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10199/how-should-i-design-a-relationship-table-for-friendship

Comment: The ID in Table PackageNextTo is an AutoIncrement required by Access.  Not something I'm actually using in coding anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your proposed `PackageNextTo` table, "ID (PK)" appears to be a surrogate key, presumably an autonumber. While I'm not a surrogate key advocate myself, I know folk who are who avoid them in a relationship tables (junction tables, linking tables, whatever). You would certainly need to enforce the candidate key (compound) of `(PackageID, NextToPackageID)` anyhow and the presence of the `ID` seems to have confused at least one person answering here. Therefore, I suggest you omit it.

To ensure the 'next to' relationship are **stored** uni-directional, add a `CHECK` constraint (or Validation Rule) e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE PackageNextTo
(
 PackageID CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
    REFERENCES Packages (PackageID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 NextToPackageID CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
    REFERENCES Packages (PackageID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CHECK (PackageID < NextToPackageID), 
 UNIQUE (PackageID, NextToPackageID)
);
```

To **show** all 'next to' relationships as bi-directional, expand them using a `VIEW` (or create a soted Query object in your usual way):

```
CREATE VIEW AdjacentPackages
AS
SELECT PackageID AS PackageID_1, 
       NextToPackageID AS PackageID_2
  FROM PackageNextTo
UNION
SELECT NextToPackageID AS PackageID_1, 
       PackageID AS PackageID_2
  FROM PackageNextTo;
```

Note that `CHECK` and `CREATE VIEW` require [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx?redir=0).

Comment: Your check and unique constraints eliminate the need for a `UNION` to remove duplicates.

Comment: @LeighRiffel: indeed, a [disjoint union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union) is what I really want but no SQL Standard or product support such a relational operator, Access included. `UNION CORRESPONDING` would be my next choice but again not supported in Access. Which brings me to my next choice `UNION`, which is supported and I have used. Because I never want duplicate rows, I never use `UNION ALL`. HTH

Comment: You will never get duplicate rows even with a `UNION ALL` due to your check and unique constraints.  You will also not get the performance hit of a sort which a `UNION` requires.

Comment: @LeighRiffel: if you and I can see that there will never be duplicate rows then the optimizer should too and is not compelled to introduce a needless sort. When I see someone using a `UNION ALL` then I have to waste my time checking whether duplicate rows could occur! I only work with relational data so I avoid non-relational constructs in SQL such as `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Indeed we can deduce that there will be no duplicates, but I doubt most optimizers would check to see if subqueries are unioning the same table and that table has a unique index and the column order is distinct and there is an ascending check constraint for the columns within within the unique index.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from on a theoretical level, but in practice `UNION ALL` gives the optimizer information it would not otherwise have about how the query should be processed.  I understand your frustration having to determine whether a `UNION ALL` will return duplicates or not, but I'd rather a human check once than the system attempt to eliminate them every time the query runs.  When I see a `UNION` I usually 'waste my time' checking to see if duplicates will occur because often they will not and the performance hit can be avoided.

Comment: @LeighRiffel: no frustration for me: I get paid to peer review code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create a view as follows:

```
SELECT ID, PackageID, NextToPackageID FROM PackageNextTo
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, NextToPackageID, PackageID FROM PackageNextTo
```

(this is Oracle syntax and may need to be modified for Access)

Comment: Examine the OP's last resultset: it shows that `(A, B)` is not the same as `(B, A)` because they have different values for `ID`, 1 and 3 respectively. Therefore, I do not think your `VIEW` should include the `ID` column because it would incorrectly associate `ID = 1` with both. I also think `UNION ALL` should be changed to `UNION` in order to remove duplicates.

Comment: @onedaywhen The OP indicates the desire to not have two entries for (A,B) and (B, A) with seperate IDs. I included the ID for completness, but it is not required for the solution. It would not be incorrect to associate ID 1 with (A,B) and (B,A), because no other ID would be appropriate. ID 3 would be assigned to a different set entirely -- (M,T) probably. If the OP were concerned about duplicates then a unique key should be created on (PackageID, NextToPackageID) [as you explained in your solution] rather than using a run time UNION to remove duplicates.

Comment: This works for what I need... just one note: I made the two select statements be "FROM PackageNextTo" .... this data is being stored in another table because one package may be next to zero or more packages.

Comment: @maneesha Of course, I miss-typed that, but have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any locations that the packages are stored in/at (like shelf number/silo/etc)? If you do, then you can have a table with locations and package at that location. To find the adjacent packages you need only to know the location id +/-1 location. The location ID would need to be unique and sequential.

If not, then you would could define a constraint (which probably means using a database engine that is more powerful the Access, maybe SQL server express?) Then you could create a trigger function that checks that the X next to Y == Y next to X on any updates.

Another option is to create a linked list structure in your table, so that the data element for X has next filled and Y and the previous element for Y has X, with the prev/next/current fields having a unique constraint on them. Eg

```
Table: Packages
PackageID (PK)
PrevPackageID (unique, allow null)
NextPackageID (unique, allow null)
PackageHeight
….
```

And then to be real sure put in a constraint or trigger function to check that prevID matches the nextID of the previous element.

Comment: A design rule of thumb states that a table should model either an entity or a relationship between entities but not both. Because you have broken this rule I think your suggested table will suffer update anomalies.